# Ubuntu 18.04 Cannot Enter Password In Terminal

Tags: command-line, password

Recently when I am asked to enter password in terminal, I cannot hit the enter key to actually enter it. Concretely, I typed my password, hit the ENTER key and nothing happened. The cursor stays in the same line. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I would boot a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media) with the purpose of verifying the key actually works (hasn't been destroyed by spilt liquid etc).  If your box allows remote login, you could `ssh` in to confirm the health of your system, but i'd start by validating your hardware (ie. does your enter key work; running `xev` give appropriate responses though you'll likely know it works by entering that command)

Comment: Are you able to type out your username and press Enter? Generally, you enter your username before the password, right? And what terminal are you using? TTY Console or `gnome-terminal` or something else?